# How to display three dimensional Objects in a 2D Game using OpenGL and orthographic Projection?

Tags: opengl, 2d

I am creating a 2D (2.5D) game using OpenGL and orthographic projection.

It is simple to have relatively flat objects, e.g. characters.
I simply use a quad with a texture of the character and move that about.

However, what is the best way to draw big objects that have depth, e.g. a big house?
Do I use one quad with a three dimensional looking represantation of the house on it, or do I use multiple quads (e.g. front, side, top)?

I prefer using one quad with a three dimensional looking texture on it. What are the drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: This is very vague. You use whatever works best for you.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I prefer the option with one quad as it is much easier to draw the representation (create the pixel house). What are the drawbacks to that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done both, I can say that using a single quad is best in circumstances where none of your larger objects take up more than one grid square and/or are square/cube-shaped.  Otherwise, you will eventually run into Z-sorting issues.

The multiple-quad solution was the best one that I found to deal with that particular situation.  IE, if you had larger, irregular-shaped objects it was best to slice them into quads that represented each grid square that they occupied.

It ultimately depends on your engine; the former is the easier, but it won't work in all situations.  The latter will, but may be overkill for the type of game you're doing.